# How do access windows-specific network activity process stats from Resource Monitor via the command line

Tags: windows, wmi

I'm trying to access these stats via the command line/wmi. How can I do so? I'm having issues.

Here is a screenshot of the statistics I'm interested in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FKCC.png

This post I found seems like it might be close, but I'm not sure how to proceed with the information from the link: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b82da95a-1c18-49ce-9bfa-e3d79ec40907/access-resouce-monitor-network-actitivy-data-programmatically?forum=perfmon